# Debian 12: why can't I install a kernel built from source?

Tags: debian

I have often built and installed linux kernels in the past, so I am surprised at how apparently difficult it now seems.

The story: I am trying to build a lustre client for Debian 12; one of the first steps is to run the `configure` script, and it fails with:

```
checking if Linux kernel was built with CONFIG_FHANDLE in or as module... no
configure: error: 

Lustre fid handling requires that CONFIG_FHANDLE is enabled in your kernel.
```

Which is why I need to compile a new kernel: `make deb-pkg`; this goes well enough, and I then install the resulting packages without error. But the system still boots up with the original kernel. As far as I can see from the various Debian docs, I've all I need, so I'm a bit stumped; there must be something I've done wrong, but what?

***Edit in reply to comment by Stephen Kitt***

```
root@debian12:~# grep FHANDLE /boot/config-$(uname -r)
CONFIG_FHANDLE=y
```

I can see in the `configure` script that they seem to check with this bit of code:

```
cat confdefs.h - <<_ACEOF >conftest.$ac_ext
/* end confdefs.h.  */

#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>

#if defined(NEED_LOCKDEP_IS_HELD_DISCARD_CONST) \
 && defined(CONFIG_LOCKDEP) \ 
 && defined(lockdep_is_held)
#undef lockdep_is_held
        #define lockdep_is_held(lock) \
                lock_is_held((struct lockdep_map *)&(lock)->dep_map)
#endif


        #include <$AUTOCONF_HDIR/autoconf.h>

int
main (void)
{
  
        #if !(defined(CONFIG_FHANDLE) || defined(CONFIG_FHANDLE_MODULE))
        #error CONFIG_FHANDLE and CONFIG_FHANDLE_MODULE not #defined
        #endif

  ;
  return 0;
};
```

Comment: What does `grep FHANDLE /boot/config-$(uname -r)` show on your system? Debian kernels ship with `CONFIG_FHANDLE` enabled.

Comment: @StephenKitt I've added it to my question